# React reference to my form's value attribute is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, ref

**First I'd like to say that I have a solution, but it seems ridiculous and there has to be a better way.** So I'll start with my ridiculous solution.

I have a form that shows what page I'm on. I want the user to be able to enter a page and go to that page on enter.

**My component looks something like:**

```
const BookPagination = (props) => {

    const history = useHistory()
    const { items, bookTitle, currentPageId } = props
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(currentPageId)
    const totalPages = items.length
    const ENTER = 13

    // items is just a bunch of arrays with info about each page (each of which have an id)

    const handlePageInput = (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === ENTER) {
            e.preventDefault()
            history.push({
                pathname: `/books/${bookTitle}/id/${items[currentPage - 1].id}` //page id's start @ 1
            })
        } else {
            setCurrentPage(e.target.value)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={'.pageSelector'}>
            <span>
                <input type="number"
                    min="1"
                    max={totalPages}
                    value={currentPage}
                    onKeyDown={handlePageInput}
                    onChange={handlePageInput}
                />
                of {totalPages}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookPagination
```

So this works... If I had a bookmark on page 20 of Moby Dick, I can go to `/books/mobydick/id/20` and the form will start with `20` in the input box and it will navigate me anywhere I want (I've excluded code for bounds checking).

## My problem:

This thing renders every single time I make a change to the input.. If I erase the 20 and put in 19 and hit enter.. that's 6 renders

`Initial`, `20->2`, `2->0`, `0->1`, `1->19`, `render new page` 
 This is because my state is updating every time..
 This is the only way I could figure out how to **start with the current page number** on page load and edit it... other tries wouldn't let me update the value if I started with one..

**How do I fix this?** 
I think what I'm looking for is React.createRef()
but I've tried the following:
**Add** `value={currentPageId}` and `ref={inputElement}` to the form

**Add** `const inputElement = React.createRef()` to the top of the component

**Remove** the state variable, currentPage

**Edit** `handlePageInput` to the following:

```
const handlePageInput = (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === ENTER) {
            e.preventDefault()
            history.push({
                pathname: `/books/${bookTitle}/id/${items[inputElement.current.value - 1].id}`
            })
        } else {
            inputElement.current.value = e.target.value
        }
    }
```

but it won't let me erase the value of the input box... clicking up and down within the input box doesn't do anything either. If I entered on page 200, I can't change it to any other page.

**Using this method,** 
if I remove `value={currentPageId}` and leave the form *without* a value attribute,

- updating my `history.push pathname` to `.../id/${items[inputElement.current.valueAsNumber - 1].id}`

I can enter in any page I want, and navigate correctly... my problem is that when I come to a page, there's nothing in the input box to start... which is how I got to updating it with `useState()` in the first place...

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try an [Uncontrolled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) with a [default value](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Remove the onChange from your input and leave the onKeyDown. Inside your handlePageInput function get the current value from a ref.

Something like this:

```
const BookPagination = (props) => {

const history = useHistory()
const { items, bookTitle, currentPageId } = props
const totalPages = items.length
const ENTER = 13
const inputElement = useRef(null);
// items is just a bunch of arrays with info about each page (each of which have an id)

const handlePageInput = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === ENTER) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const currentValue = inputElement.current.value;
        history.push({
            pathname: `/books/${bookTitle}/id/${items[currentValue - 1].id}` //page id's start @ 1
        })
    }
}

return (
    <div className={'.pageSelector'}>
        <span>
            <input type="number"
                ref={inputElement}
                min="1"
                max={totalPages}
                defaltValue={currentPageId}
                onKeyDown={handlePageInput}
            />
            of {totalPages}
        </span>
    </div>
)
}

export default BookPagination
```

Comment: So i'm a big confused by the `else {setCurrentPage(e.target.value)}`. Was this supposed to be removed from your answer? I also have buttons that let me go forward/back one page and when I do, the number within the input bo doesn't update, even when currentPageId is updated...

To clarify, when I log inputElement to the console.. defaultValue continues to update, but whatever page I started on remains the value of 'valueAsNumber' which is interesting..

Comment: Sorry. Yes, that should have been removed. The current page is no longer stored as a state value. As long as you keep it as a statefull value the component will render each time it is updated. Consider creating a codesandbox that demonstrates the problem for better help.